# How to implement foreign key field which displays the actual field value instead of "id"in Tortoise-ORM and display it on the FastAPI-admin interface?

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I am using Tortoise-ORM which is connected to PostgreSQL, and monitored by Postico. How to create a Foreign Key Field in the Tortoise-ORM such that it is a key in the table which acts a foreign key in another table. I am having problem to display it in the admin interface. FastAPI-admin interface.

#models.py file to create the table and its attributes
city = fields.ForeignKeyField('us.City', null=True)

#resources.py file to show the fields on the FastAPI-admin interface
fields = [“city”]

I am creating the above field called “city” which acts a foreign key in this table. Instead of the actual values of the city, i.e., Mumbai, etc, its “id” is displaying in the database and on the FastAPI-admin interface. How to resolve the issue?

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with issues, but there are some expectation of you. Please spend a few minuets to [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, and expected results. All as [formatted text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) or even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/), but - **no images**.